# Idiomatic way to have different different subclasses in swift have different default values

Tags: swift, inheritance, initialization

I have an abstract class

```
class AbstractDevicePrimaryAnnotationView: MKAnnotationView {

    let maskImage:UIImage = UIImage()
    var shape:CALayer

    override init(annotation: MKAnnotation?, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        // init mine
        self.shape = CALayer()
        // init parents
        super.init(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        // additional setup     
        self.layer.addSublayer(self.shape)
        self.shape.mask = CALayer()
        self.shape.mask?.contents = self.maskImage.CGImage
    }
}
```

I want subclasses to be able to have different (and real) values for the `maskImage` var. But try for the life of me, nothing seems to work.

```
class SubclassAnnoationView: AbstractDevicePrimaryAnnoationView {
    override let maskImage:UIImage! = UIImage(named: "mapValvePrimaryAnnotationMask")!
}
```

I've tried `let`, `var`, `lazy var`. Nothing seems to work. I get a variety of compiler errors. I could make it an `Optional`, but that seems like a cop out. Isn't there a way to let subclasses designate their own constant/static values? Hopefully one that's idiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
var maskImage: UIImage {
  return UIImage()
}
```

Then each subclass just do

```
override var maskImage: UIImage {
   return //whatever image here
}
```

Comment: In this case, I need a real `var` (or `let`) because I need to retain it myself. If I don't, bad things happen. Otherwise, yes, I could just use the classic subclass method (or computed property) trick.